# Trying to learn comprehensions, want to create and populate a dict with list comprehension. without knowing the keys first

Tags: python

from a dataquest question.
the keys it's supposed to find are

{'17+', '9+', '4+', '12+'}

so it's a short list, it'd be easy to *cheat* and just use the four items as in the list comprehension at the end, but there has to be some way to just iterate through a generated list of keys for larger data.

```
opened_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)
opened_file.close()
content_ratings = dict()

c_ratings = set([x[10] for x in apps_data[1:]])

for x in c_ratings:
    content_ratings[x] = 0
print(content_ratings)


# content_ratings['4+'] = len([x for x in apps_data[1:] if x[10] == '4+'])    
# content_ratings['9+'] = len([x for x in apps_data[1:] if x[10] == '9+'])    
# content_ratings['12+'] = len([x for x in apps_data[1:] if x[10] == '12+'])    
# content_ratings['17+'] = len([x for x in apps_data[1:] if x[10] == '17+'])
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension.

```py
{r: len([x for x in apps_data[1:] if x[10] == r]) for r in c_ratings}
```

Comment: This is close, but it required that you know that one of the values is '4+' in order to use.